# Put and align text with the first div of three (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make this layout (I've made a picture to explain what i want to do):

[image]

So I've 4 divs where I'm going to put some text inside. I've used flexbox and justify content to align them center, but i want to put a text "Latest News" that is aligned with the first div (in this case Element 1).

I'm not able to think about an elegant solution to my problem, so I'm here to ask for help.

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p class="section-title">Latest News</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Element 1</div>
  <div class="box">Element 2</div>
  <div class="box">Element 3</div>
  <div class="box">Element 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you put <p> inside wrapper?

Comment: If i do that my text will be put next to the first div, thats not what i want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do it, and it depends how dynamic your `box` elements are going to be.

One simple solution that works for *n* boxes is to include the section title to the first box and give it `position: absolute` whilst adding `margin-top` to the wrapper to make space for the title.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJpOrM

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

.section-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <p class="section-title">Latest News</p>
    Element 1
  </div>
  <div class="box">Element 2</div>
  <div class="box">Element 3</div>
  <div class="box">Element 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this actually works fine for what i need to do with my boxes.

Comment: You can also remove the `.header` and instead add a `margin-top` to `.wrapper`

Comment: Thanks @Oriol, I've updated the solution to use `margin-top` instead, makes the HTML cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have a fixed width for your boxes, the easiest solution is to make the section-title a fixed width too:

```
.section-title {
    width: 1260px; //This is merely 300 * 4 + the margin
    margin: auto;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpWmJV

Comment: Thank you for the answer Dave, but Christopher's solution works better for what i need.